# PHP catch echoed ouptut, save it and erase

Tags: php, buffer

I need to

1. echo
2. save what is echoed to variable
3. do not display that echo

because I need to.

As far I was sure it could be done with buffers like:

```
ob_start();
$parallelcurl->startRequest($data[$name]['repository'], 'requestDone_list');
array_push($repository, ob_get_contents());
ob_end_flush();
```

But it actually echoes things saving them but no erase - I see loads of echoes that I dont want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `ob_end_flush()`, you need [`ob_end_clean();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).